# Alterar altura do pai pela altura do filho

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Gostaria de fazer isso em CSS:

```
$("div.slider").height($("div.slider div.slide").height())
```

é possível?

O objetivo é criar um slide aonde a altura da div conteiner (slider) seja sempre, e em tempo de execução, da mesma altura que a div filho (slide)

Tentei da forma abaixo mas sumiu tudo:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 
//$("div.slider").height($("div.slider div.slide").height())

const blocos = $("div.slider div.slide");

function startslider() {  

  ativa = $("div.slider div.ativa")
  
  if (!$(ativa).next().length) {
    ativa = blocos[0]
  }
  
   $(ativa)
   .removeClass("ativa")
   .next()
   .addClass("ativa")
  
   setTimeout(startslider, 5000)
}

setTimeout(startslider, 5000)

$("nav button.anterior").click(function(){

  prev = $("div.slider div.ativa").prev();  
  prev = prev.length ? prev : blocos[ blocos.length - 1 ];  
  mostraBloco(prev);
  
})

$("nav button.proximo").click(function(){
 
  next = $("div.slider div.ativa").next();    
  next = next.length ? next : blocos[0];    
  mostraBloco(next);
  
})

/* Função para exibir as imagens */
function mostraBloco(next) {
 
  ativa = $("div.slider div.ativa")
  
  $(ativa).removeClass("ativa")
  $(next).addClass("ativa")
  
}
});
</script>
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

div.slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height:300px;
}

div.slider:hover {
  animation-play-state:paused;
}
div.slider div.slide {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
div.slider div.slide img {
 width:100%;
}
div.slider div.ativa {
  display: block;
}
div.slider div.ativa img{
 animation: slider 1s linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div.slider div.ativa img:hover {
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

@keyframes slider {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);        
    } 
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.1);     
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

div.slider div.slide span {
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 line-height:40px;
 bottom:0;
 z-index:500;
 color:rgb(255,255,255);
 text-align:center;
}
div.slider nav {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
 background-color:rgb(0,0,0,.5);
 z-index:400;
 text-align:center;
}
div.slider nav button.anterior,
div.slider nav button.proximo {
 position:absolute;
 width:100px;
 height:40px;
 text-align:center;
}
div.slider nav button.anterior{
 left:10%;
}
div.slider nav button.proximo{
 right:10%;
}
div.slider nav button.proximo label {
 top:calc(50%-20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
 <div class="slide fade ativa">
   <img  src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" />
   <span>Este é 1</span>
 </div>
 <div class="slide fade">
   <img  src="http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" />
   <span>Este é 2</span>
 </div>

 <nav>
  <button class="anterior">Anterior</button>
  <button class="proximo">Próximo</button>
 </nav>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Cara é só colocar height:auto no Pai, assim ele terá sempre a altura do Filho. A não ser que o filho tenha `float:left` ai vc tem que fazer um clearfix pra corrigir.

Comment: não tem float left e não fucionou. O código completo está nessa outra pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295962/erro-no-final-do-loop-do-slide-show

Comment: Cara aproveita e coloca a parte do HTML que está envolvida na questão também. Não precisa do HTML da página inteira apenas da onde está o problema

Comment: O códio completo está nessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295962/erro-no-final-do-loop-do-slide-show. Acha que devo repetir aqui também?

Comment: Acho que não precisa por enquanto... Mas tem que olhar pra ver se está faltando algo. Mas a principio o que eu falei no primeiro comentário era pra ter funcionado. Assim que der eu olho e te falo

Comment: ok, alterei aqui tb